# Emulator Vs. Device: I can add item to arraylist in emulator but on device I can only add the first item

Tags: android, listview

I am writing an app, which by pressing a button it adds new field to the list. It works fine on the emulator, but when I test it on the device it only adds 1 item and after that doesn't add any more item. It doesn't even show any error. I am stuck and I have no idea what is causing the issue. Did anyone had experience similar issue before?

I simply add and then notify the adapter with the update

```
listItems.add("FROM :"+start+"-"+finish);

// update the list
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I highly appreciate any comment on that.

Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: check with different emulator . its shows actual problem .

Comment: I have tested the app with different version of Android Emulator, and works with all of them. But as soon as I run it on my device, I am only able to add the first item, but I can't add the second item.

Comment: is it fresh apk in your device ? its very strange.

Comment: yeah I have uninstall the installed apk, and reinstalled it, but still the same issue

Comment: can we chat tomorrow because my time is over and going to home ?

Comment: can you send me apk for testing?

Comment: Thanks mate, I have managed to fix it. I have answered my question below :)

Comment: so which is your minimum api >

Comment: I have set the minimum API to 3, so it can work on all version of Android :)

Comment: ha ha lol. Now Happy ? Enjoy Budy.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured that out. 
In Android device version 4.0 under Setting>{}Developer options 
there is an option under Apps section called "Don't keep activities.
I just needed to simply deselect that option. :)
I hope that helps others.